# CiviCRM: Custom report: list related contacts with contact details

Tags: report, civicrm

## The Problem

I am using CiviCRM to manage all our sponsor contacts. The sponsors are in the group "Sponsors". Some sponsors have related contact persons.

I need a list of all sponsors with their contact information and all the related contact persons for this sponsor. This could look like the following:

```
Sponsor ACME  | Tel: +1-23456     | Mail: acme@example.com
  - Contact A | Tel: +1-23456 - 1 | Mail: a.acme@example.com | Relation: Employee
  - Contact B | Tel: +2-4567890   | Mail: b@example.com      | Relation: Sponsor contact

Sponsor Foo   | Tel: +2-9876      | Mail: foo@example.com

Sponsor Baz   | Tel: +6-6666      | Mail: baz@example.com

Sponsor Bar   | Tel: +4-4444      | Mail: bar@example.com
  - Contact C | Tel: +3-555555555 | Mail: c@example.com      | Relation: Employee
```

**Question:** Is it possible to create such a report with CiviCRM?

## What I tried

### Available reports

I tried to use a relationship report, but this does not include sponsors without related contacts. Listing all contacts in the group sponsors however does not show up the related contact persons.

I think this is a common request, so I am pretty sure I a missing out something.

### Custom reports

If it is not possible with the available reports, is it possible to create a custom report for that?

I saw, that the file *wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Report/Form/Contact/CurrentEmployer.tpl* only includes this file: *wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Report/Form.tpl*. So do the other .tpl contact reports. It seems like there should also be another .php file for the database stuff.

The tutorials I found only dealt with custom fields or so but I did not find any to include the related contacts like shown above.

Answer (score 1):

might want to check and follow the instructions here:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviReport+Reference

You will need to write a custom report for your needs. Please do so as an extension and publish your work so others can reuse :)

thanx

lobo